# Pyspark grouby taking a very long time

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by

I've searched around quite a bit, and asked my professor, but not sure what the problem is. I have a test data set of 20,000 points. I perform a groupby on this to get the sum and it takes maybe 30 seconds, which is reasonable since this is on a jupyter notebook.

However, when I put in the larger test dataframe of 1.5 Million data points, it takes hours. Everything else, even on the large dataset happens quickly (multiple conditional joins, etc). My professor thinks that one key occurs very frequently and this could cause an issue. But I cant even check this.

When I run

```
df = df.groupby('ID').count().sort('ID').desc()).show()
```

on the small data set it works very fast and says that one value has 25 points, while all others are below 5. So maybe there is a key explosion. However, on the larger dataframe, well ive been waiting half an hour now.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: You can check the spark application url and see if only one/two task is taking for a long time, while rest were finished. Where the data is stored HDFS or s3, And what is file size? Are you running this job in cluster ?

Comment: the file is on my computer right now (final is on HDFS) and no not running it in a cluster. Running it on one machine.

Comment: Spark is designed for a multi node cluster in order to achieve distributed computing or computing in parallel on data, on the other hand ,a single node library like pandas will outperform spark on a single node because it is designed for that